# External HDD no longer asks to "recycle" deleted files, only deletes permanently

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, recycle-bin

EDIT: Solved by restarting computer (cue rolling eyes)- it's strange that it worked the second time I did this, but not the first. Ah well, question can be considered closed.

I'm on Windows 10, and this is a new issue that's popped up in the past few days. I have two external hard drive disks - previously, when I deleted files, they would send them to the recycle bin. Now though, they no longer do so, and only ask me if I want to get rid of them permanently, like on a USB stick.This is an issue because if I ever accidentally delete a file, I want to be able to recover it immediately.

This could have to do with the fact that one of my hard drives fell down lightly the other day (though it is strange, because they're otherwise working perfectly fine, and this also affects the one that didn't fall). When I click on the Recycle Bin properties, its only location is my internal C: drive - I assume it's supposed to have the other drives as well? Is there a way to add them back? I've tried unplugging and plugging them back in, to no avail.

As I understand it, each external HDD has a specific hidden "recycle bin" that is linked to the desktop recycle bin. Both of them still had these, though I deleted one, to see if that changed anything, because I thought I read that if I unplugged and plugged the HDD back in it would recreate it (which, uh, it didn't).

I tried chkdsk and scannow on one of the drives, but not both of them. Since both are exhibiting the same behavior, I'm mostly making tests on the one containing less data.

So now I'm kinda stumped. I have no idea if there's a way to fix this, and searching online gave me no real clue - most posts are about deleting the external HDD recycle bins, which obviously is not what I want.

I'm not sure if there's a way to check if the drives are fixed or removable - in Disk Management, nothing really seems to have changed, although oddly enough they only show up in the "volume" list above if I change their policies by clicking in the list below from "quick removal" to "better performance" (and vice-versa) - which didn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do not edit your question to mark it solved. Answer it yourself instead, containing the steps you used to solve it.

Comment: Well, I tried that below, but I was told that "this is not an answer" and to "add the information to my question". I'll undelete it, then.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't have the "see deleted answers" privilege, so I didn't know about it.

Comment: @Dissentrix A reboot may **_resolve_** an issue, but it is not a _solution_ to the issue you describe... There's a fundamental difference. That fundamental difference matters when someone else has the same/similar issue and I can guarantee a reboot, in and of itself, will not solve the issue you describe _(if a reboot was the solution, your prior reboot(s) would have resolved the issue)_, which is why I commented that your answer is not an answer, and to please add the information to your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently restarting my computer solved this. It's bizarre, because I'd already restarted it before with no results, but whatever. Issue's closed.

Comment: This is not an answer... please add this information to your question by editing it.

Comment: @JW0914: This is, as easy or improbable the solution may seem to be, an answer. And it is better to recognize this as an answer than to add the info to the question.

Comment: A reboot may **_resolve_** an issue, but it is not a _solution_ to the issue you describe... There's a fundamental difference. That fundamental difference matters when someone else has the same/similar issue and I can guarantee a reboot, in and of itself, will not solve the issue you describe _(if a reboot was the solution, your prior reboot(s) would have resolved the issue)_ - a reboot of an OS, in and of itself, cannot, and does not, fix partition corruption, Recycle Bin directory corruption, or master file table corruption, nor does it make changes to system settings _(in this context)_.

Comment: Perhaps. It solved my issue, though, so I fail to see why I should keep this opened as a problem with no solution (since there is no problem anymore), and will thus mark this as the answer.

Comment: @gargoylebident Thanks for the trivia, I guess, but in the meantime, I don't have the problem I opened this issue for anymore.

So unless you're suggesting I willingly cause that problem to myself somehow in order to try solving this issue for these theoretical other users that do not exist right now, I don't really get why you're on my back literally two and a half years since this issue happened as this issue WAS solved for me.

Do you have this issue?

Comment: @Dissentrix This isn't a traditional forum. It's not to help you. It's to help the people who want an answer to this question in the future. No such thing as necroposting on SE. On the contrary, updating and improving posts is encouraged. Yes, I do have this issue, and your "solution" is expectedly useless.

Comment: @gargoylebident Cool. I don't really get how anything that you typed concerns me, though, since unlike you, my problem was solved by restarting my computer.

You want to ask these other people if they have any ideas? Go ahead, I'm not stopping you. But the only suggestion I can personally provide, which HAS worked for me, is "restart the computer". Doesn't work for you? Sorry to hear that - once more, unless your own suggestion is for me to try and willingly cause this problem to myself again, I fail to see what more I can contribute here.

Comment: @Dissentrix you'll get it when you start reading because I've addressed everything. Again, this is not a forum. On this site, any single question can only be asked _once_. I cannot "ask these other people." My question will be marked as duplicate and removed because _this question exists_ and is erroneously marked "Answered." Your most (and only) sensible contribution is removing the "Accepted" flag from your own "answer" (the green checkmark to the left of it).

Comment: @gargoylebident Sorry, but I'm not going to be bullied into removing the actual solution that worked for me. Anyone wants to jump in and help you (which is what I meant by "ask these other people" in the first place), can do so.

My problem- the reason I posted this in the first place - is solved. I'm sorry yours isn't, but it doesn't concern me, or this question.

Answer (score 0):

To re-enable the Recycle Bin:

1. File Explorer → `C:\$RECYCLE.BIN` → Right-click `Recycle Bin` → *Properties*
2. *General* tab → Highlight the applicable drive(s)
3. *Settings for selected location* → Tick *Custom size* → *OK*

Comment: Hmm - I just tried this, but similarly to the desktop recycle bin properties I described in my original post, my two hard drives don't even appear on the list of available locations.

Comment: @Dissentrix I misread information in your question... if the external drive(s) have a `$RECYCLE.BIN` directory, then it's likely the directory has become corrupted. To fix: rename the `$RECYCLE.BIN` directory `$RECYCLE.BIN.corrupt` on the affected drive, then delete  `$RECYCLE.BIN.corrupt`. Navigate out of, then back into, the root of the drive and perform the steps in the answer to verify the issue is resolved. If not, run the following on each drive: `chkdsk <drive>: /offlinescanandfix` Beyond that, it would be more efficient to backup the contents and reformat the external as NTFS.

Comment: @Dissentrix _Cont'd..._ It's also entirely possible the  `$RECYCLE.BIN` on an internal/permanently connected drive could be at fault _(I don't know why corruption of one  `$RECYCLE.BIN` affects the  `$RECYCLE.BIN` on other drives, I only know it occurs)_, so you may want to repeat the renaming steps in my previous comment on all drives, but don't re-enter the root of any drive after deleting  `$RECYCLE.BIN.corrupt` until all have had their recycle bins renamed and deleted. If these steps resolve your issue, I'll add them to the answer.